# Didn't invoke textViewDidChangeSelection when one click and long press a word on UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

If I double-click one word on a UITextView, textViewDidChangeSelection is invoked.  However, one short click and then a long press on a word selects the word, but doesn't invoke the textViewDidChangeSelection.

How can I invoke the textViewDidChangeSelection when I one short click and long press on one word?

If this can't be done, I want one short click and long press on one word not to select the word.  How can I do this?

Thanks.